# Why is in PHP/.NET CMS all pages are build using ?id=<number> and not direct php page

Tags: php, .net, code-injection

In PHP/.NET we generally see that all the pages on web site are displayed using one php file with id parameter. eg. http://example.org/content.php?id=90. We know that every page can be built independently like http://example.org/1.php , 2.php etc etc. so why is single page entrusted with responsibility of displaying all the pages with an id parameter? This behavior is prevalent in many .NET web sites also.

Br,
Hemanshu.

Comment: Because less code is needed if you use one php file for displaying different data.

Comment: Are you proposing a separate .php source file for each page, or just some URL rewriting so that the same source file can still be used to render multiple URLs, and you just want to see the page ID in the path instead of in the query?

Comment: Could you perhaps explain why *you* think having multiple pages would be better?

Comment: Because you can include as many other php/html/css/script files and database sources conditionally when and only when they're needed and the id is just a condition to which page resources are associated.

Comment: Ultimately the content for all the pages has to be written somewhere either in HTML/php or any other content file. So when we have separate files already why is there any need of id parameter as it opens up the pandora box of SQL injection possibilities and i think separate page approach is more secure because of its simplicity and that way we can avoid if/case conditions in our code. What do you guys think?

Comment: If you want this, use plain html and php or other programming language only for queries (as long as user input is required to be loaded/displayed). Then you'll have static pages. But they're harder to maintain, that's why it isn't the prefered way in doing that.

Comment: Yyeah I'm really not convinced that you can conduct an SQL injection attack with just numbers. If you have a personal web site with 5-10 subpages and no logins etc. then sure, go ahead and implement them separately. But when you have an "actual" web site with 1000+ subpages there's no way you can manage handling all of them separately. What if you want to make a change to the page layout, are you going to edit all of them by hand?

Comment: Ok. Yeah, That's correct indeed. Thanks for quick response to everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generally what a CMS does:

Lets say we have three modules (page elements):

1 form

2 top menu bar

3 left menu bar

Now you have to make page, which requires all of them, if you do it statically (in a single .html/.php file) it will be easy just save module contents as *main.php* and make a link to the page.

But then you have to make another page, which still requires the top menu but doesn't need the form and the side menu has few more sections. You cannot load *main.php* so this way, you'll have to make different page with duplicated main menu section.
Instead of doing all that, it is much easier if you have one *content.php* file, that will low only the needed modules and module elements (i.e. side bar additional sections in the above case) and only when it is needed.